# Trying to separate sessions for MVC apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

We are working on a C# MVC project that has two MVC UIs, the frontend and the admin section. We're currently using IIS Express for debugging locally. When debugging both apps, we can see values from both apps shared in the Session.

I modified our MyApp.vs\config\applicationhost.config and added an app pool section for each app, and set them to use it, like this:

```
<sites>
    <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="MyApp.Frontend" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="MyAppFrontendAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\myname\Source\Repos\MyApp\MyApp.Frontend" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51415:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="MyApp.Admin" id="5">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="MyAppAdminAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\myname\Source\Repos\MyApp\MyApp.Admin" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58534:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

However, I still see variables from both apps in the Session.

How can I ensure that each app works in it's own, separate, Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions in ASP.NET have a client-side component (cookie), and the ability for an app to read the cookie (and thus restore the session) depends on three factors:

1. The ability to receive the cookie in the first place. Cookies are domain-bound, so if both sites are running on localhost, for example, they will each receive each other's cookies. However, this would not be an issue if they were deployed to foo.com and bar.com.
2. The ability to decrypt the cookie. This is controlled by the machine key being used for the app. By default, ASP.NET will generate a single machine key for the system and use that for everything, which then allows any apps on that machine to read each other's cookies. To disable this, you should give each application its own explicit and distinct machine key.
3. Finally, the cookie name. The cookie used for persisting session state is customizable per application, but defaults to a standard name of `ASP.NET_SessionId`. Obviously, if both sites are using the same cookie name for their sessions, then they will essentially share that. Therefore, the most direct way to separate sessions for applications is to assign each a unique session cookie name.

   ```
   <system.web>
       <sessionState cookieName="foo" />
   </system.web>
   ```